# Can anyone identify the plane in this old photo?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-identification

It belonged to my uncle. May have been 1930s vintage.

[image: Old photo of single wing plane in field with crowd]

Comment: It might help to say where in the world your uncle lived. Hopefully, somebody will figure this out.

Comment: If you think you know the answer, please write it as an answer not a comment.

Comment: I will say its odd how many planes in the late 20's early 30's looked alike.

Answer (score 17):

It's probably a [Stinson Junior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinson_Junior). Built in the late 1920s and early 1930s.

Comment: Absolutely: some good pictures here: http://www.skytamer.com/Stinson_SM-8A.html. There is one picture from the same angle, and it's a 100% match.